# IsEsclated Checbox is unchecked automatically when the case is closed

Tags: case, escalation

The IsEscalated checkbox is getting unchecked automatically when that case got closed which is escalated. So my doubt is, this behaviour of unchecking by itself is the standard salesforce functionality..??

Comment: I believe it's the standard functionality of salesforce.

Comment: yep.. I also believe the same . Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [**documentation**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cases_fields.htm&type=0) (First field)

> Indicates that an escalation rule escalated a case. The escalation
>   icon disappears when a case is closed or no longer meets escalation
>   rule criteria.

Comment: Hi Himanshu.. Yes we escalate the case by using two ways.. whenever the milestone got violated this escalated field will get true and through by code also like whenever sla state of the case is violated this escalated should check as true. So am not able to find from this escalated checkbox is getting unchecked when case is closed. and the exit criteria for the milestone is case status is closed. Thanks for responding.

Comment: when case get closed Salesforce update this field.